# confidence interval for linear regression coefficient with error following a t distribution

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, linear-model

I have this linear model $$=_0+_1+$$

where the error terms  are iid from a student t-distribution with constant degrees of freedom k. I want to construct a 95% confidence interval for $\hat{\beta_1}$. The general formula is ($\hat{\beta_1}-\alpha * se(\hat{\beta_1}), \hat{\beta_1}+\alpha * se(\hat{\beta_1})$). Normally if the error  follows a N(0,1) distribution, then $\alpha$ would be the 0.975 quantile for the N(0 1) distribution, which is 1.96. But since  follows at distribution here, I am not sure which distribution should I extract the quantile from.

Should I use quantile from the same t distribution where the error is from, or should I use a t distribution with degree of freedom =n-2 (n is the sample size, and minus 2 because I have $\beta_0, \beta_1$ in the model). Can anyone share some thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: The quantile depends only on the confidence interval's "width" that you prefer. If it's a 95% confidence interval, why should your quantile be different. It will be the same: `0.975`.

Comment: sorry I meant to say which distribution should I extract the quantile from

Comment: you said you wanted to extract it from the t-distribution, don't you.

Comment: yeah, but I am not sure which degree of freedom should I use? Should I use k or n-2?

Comment: I don't know. The t-distribution was your assumption. What degree of freedom do you assume for your error term?

Comment: it's just a question that we asked to solve, so the k is given as a fixed number say 5, but n-2=38 in the example.

Comment: Obviously this degree of freedom of the error term can have nothing to do with the degrees of freedom of this linear model. The former is a frivolous assumption. Maybe your professor wants you to fit the real data to a certain degree of freedom and then compute a confidence interval. But I guess you may be not equipped to do this - too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm going to assume that you still use OLS estimation to fit your model (though you could easily justify departure from that and use the MLE instead in this case).  I'm also going to assume that you use a scaled T-distribution for the error, still using the multiplier $\sigma$ to allow the error term variance to have a variable scale.  If you don't include this parameter, just take $\sigma = 1$ in my answer and the result is the same.*

Assuming you used OLS estimation, your estimated coefficient vector can be written as:

$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}
= \boldsymbol{\beta} + (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \boldsymbol{\epsilon}.$$

We then have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}) 
&= [(\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T}] \mathbb{V}(\boldsymbol{\epsilon}) [(\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T}]^\text{T} \\[10pt]
&= \frac{k \sigma^2}{k-2} \cdot (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{I} [(\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T}]^\text{T} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{k \sigma^2}{k-2} \cdot (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x} (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{k \sigma^2}{k-2} \cdot (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Therefore, taking $\mathbf{M} \equiv (\mathbf{x}^\text{T} \mathbf{x})^{-1}$ to be the inverse-Gramian matrix in the regression, the *true* standard error here is:

$$\begin{align}
\text{se}_i \equiv \mathbb{S}(\hat{\beta}_i) 
&= \sqrt{\frac{k}{k-1}} \cdot \sigma \cdot M_{i,i},
\end{align}$$

and the estimated standard error is:

$$\begin{align}
\hat{\text{se}}_i \equiv \hat{\mathbb{S}}(\hat{\beta}_i) 
&= \sqrt{\frac{k}{k-1}} \cdot \hat{\sigma} \cdot M_{i,i}.
\end{align}$$

As you can see, the only difference here from the case of a normal distribution is that you have the additional factor $\sqrt{\tfrac{k}{k-2}}$ in the standard error term.  If you add this additional factor into the standard error for your confidence interval, it will account for the effect of the degrees-of-freedom parameter on the error variance.

Comment: +1 But then what happens if $k\le2?$

Comment: In that case the error variance is infinite, so the estimator standard error is also infinite.

Comment: The underlying question concerns whether this formula attains the desired coverage.  For smallish datasets and smaller degrees of freedom, I (and, I believe, the OP) suspect it might not, due to the heavy tails of the error variables.